# jQuery knob tron skin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

If anyone has used this plugin before :

https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

im trying to apply the skin : "tron"

tried to add `<input data-skin="tron">` but didnt work , also tried in the initialization code:

```
$(".dial").knob({       
        readOnly:true,
        thickness:0.05,
        width:100,
        fgColor:"#cc0000",
        bgColor:"#ccc",
        skin:"tron"

        });
```

anyone knows what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just in case anyone was searching for same answer , should try this , found in the demo page , dont why such code is not included in the source script though !

include this as option in the knob method:

```
draw : function () {

                        // "tron" case
                        if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                            this.cursorExt = 0.3;

                            var a = this.arc(this.cv)  // Arc
                                , pa                   // Previous arc
                                , r = 1;

                            this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                            if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                                pa = this.arc(this.v);
                                this.g.beginPath();
                                this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, pa.s, pa.e, pa.d);
                                this.g.stroke();
                            }

                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                            this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, a.s, a.e, a.d);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                            this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even its a very late answer, you can use the [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin where you can achive the tron skin with simple CSS customization.

Check the below demo:

## [`Demo - JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/axv1bLdb/)

Screenshot:
[image: JavaScript roundSlider plugin with tron skin]