# How to use jqueryKnob's tron skin?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-knob, round-slider

Well this is my first use of the jqueryKnob plugin. I am trying to use the format option and the skin option in this plugin but it doesnt seem to work. For the skin issue I tried [jQuery knob tron skin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22810583/3697102) but was of no help. Where am I possibly going wrong?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.dial').knob({
            readOnly:true,
            fgColor:"#D07321",
            inputColor:"#3e4040",
            thickness: 0.1,
            skin:"tron",

            draw : function () {

                // "tron" case
                if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                    this.cursorExt = 0.3;

                    var a = this.arc(this.cv)  // Arc
                        , pa                   // Previous arc
                        , r = 1;

                    this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                    if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                        pa = this.arc(this.v);
                        this.g.beginPath();
                        this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                        this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, pa.s, pa.e, pa.d);
                        this.g.stroke();
                    }

                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                    this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, a.s, a.e, a.d);
                    this.g.stroke();

                    this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                    this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    this.g.stroke();

                    return false;
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input title="" type="text" value="75" class="dial">
```

Comment: Actually what is your problem here ? what doesn't work ? Can you explain about your requirement and the issue you are facing...

Comment: Actually I am not being able to use the tron skin but can't use it like the way given in the link above.

Comment: still it makes confusion.. in which way you can't use ? just explain your need and issue, also update any screenshot or fiddle for better understanding..

Comment: @Soundar R, well are you aware of the "Tron" skin available in the plugin? That is what I want to use but how? Because according to the docs I have tried but failed. Check this page for the tron skin http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/.

Comment: Yes now i got this.. Are you want to achieve this with jquery knob or any alternate plugin can do ?

Comment: have you seen my below answer.. is this suitable for your requirement / is this solves your problem ?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it out yet but from seeing it, YES, it is what I am after. Using roundSlider dynamic value update will be easy, right? Once I try your code I will check it green.

Comment: Yes, that's very flexible..

Comment: But it seems that we have to our own css. (Not good at it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122641/discussion-between-soundar-r-and-ayan).

Comment: had you seen the final demo for the smooth color change ?  http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/635/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is you missed the **data-skin="tron"** attribute in the element.

Check the updated demo: [**`Demo with knob`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/qDbLg/54/)

> Alternatively I suggest you to use the [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin which
>   is made up of basic DOM elements. So you can **customize** the overall
>   control appearance **through the CSS** itself, and no need of much more
>   scripts.
>
> Here i make the same demo with roundSlider, check the demo: [**`Demo with roundSlider`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/625/)
>
> Also you can easily customize by yourself: [**`Additional DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/626/)
>
> You can check more appearance of roundSlider from here:
>
> **http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances**